# How can I align text inside a button along with an image?

Tags: html, css, button, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I want to make a button with an image and some writing but it keeps in aligning it to the bottom or to the top. Below is my code:

```
<button><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com">&nbsp;Google</button>
```

[image] Google

Can you please help?

Comment: Many ways to do this. This is not the quickest / cleanest, but it's my go-to. ```<button style="display:flex;"><img style="margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto; " src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com">&nbsp;<p style="margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto; ">Google</p></button>```

Answer (score 1):

By using `flexbox`, you can achieve this easily.

```css
button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<button><img src="https://www.designbust.com/download/1016/png/google_logo_png_transparent512.png">&nbsp;Google</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Abin Thaha already posted, may be you were faster :)

```html
<button style="display: inline-flex;align-items: center;"><img style="vertical-align: middle" src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com">&nbsp;Google</button>
```